# eclipse (3.5 & 3.6) crashes in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-10.04

i have a problem with eclipse within ubuntu 10.04 (x86). i installed eclipse by downloading the zip-file, not from the sources. everything worked just fine until i decided to try eclipse 3.6 which i downloaded just as i did with 3.5...

well i saved 3.6 in another directory than 3.5, started it and opened a workspace that i created with 3.5. after working a bit with 3.6 i notices the following problem:

at some times, when i type sth like CLASSNAME. or VARIABLE. (that is when the code-completion dialog pops up), eclipse crashes, when i try to

- close the code completion window (e.g. by pressing ESC)
- select sth from the code completion window

or anything else. this problem did NOT occur within 3.5 at ANY time. well - switching back to the old 3.5 did not solve the problem. the crashes now happened also in this version :(

so i tried to:

- delete the /home/USER/.eclipse dir
- reinstall java from the sources
- create a completely new workspace
- tried the eclipse version from sources (3.5)

nothing helped :(

i'm out of ideas... how do i get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [bug 308731](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=308731), which is XulRunner related.

> I confirm that the Steffen's solution works for me and it is necessary to set
>   the property "`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath`".
>
> I set:

```
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/bin/xulrunner-1.9.2
```

> in my [`eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)

[image: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=160189]
(crash when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on content assist selection)

Comment: I've had similar issues but the only references I've found online have been to use x86 bit on 64 versions, switching to that fixed my issue, but possibly this is related? Anyway, good reference, thanks.

Comment: well this SEEMS to fix the problem :) meaning it didn't show up again in the last minutes of trying... hope it stays this way... thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` at the end of your eclipse.ini file

It works for me :)