# Any major problems with Helios?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I have just seen that new major release (**[3.6 Helios](http://www.eclipse.org/helios/)**) of eclipse is available for download. I want to try it, but before that I want to know if anybody experienced any major problems.

I want to determine If I could try this or not, since my project setup is complex and easily takes 2, 3 hours normally; I don't want to take any risk.

Comment: No (natural) language packs are available yet, just English.

Comment: [To resolve problems/crashes with 1.6.0_21 and helios](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Oracle.2FSun_VM_1.6.0_21_on_Windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No major issue sp far.

The main problems I have seen are platform specific, like this [crash in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190000/eclipse-3-5-3-6-crashes-in-ubuntu/3190031#3190031).
Small differences are noted in this [blog post](http://maruhgar.blogspot.com/2010/07/helios-eclipse-36.html).

As usual, I always prefer a full Eclipse installation beside the ones I already have.
And for major update, I like to recreate a workspace dedicated for that release, just to be on the safe side.
That way, my old Eclipse release still has its own workspace fully functional.
I also test the plugins in both version by using a [shared dropins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891).

Answer (score 2):

Yes i experienced a major problem with helios, but only in WTP context. If you work with WTP you should immediately update to [WTP-M-3.2.1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.2.1/M-3.2.1-20100701091247/wtp-M-3.2.1-20100701091247.zip). This should fix the issue of taking up to a minute for hot deployment (re-publishing to the server).  [The eclipse bug issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317852).

Answer (score 1):

The most disturbing thing for me was the way j2ee projects are configured: there is no more j2ee dependencies, and it is not obvious at the first glance to see you have to use resource assembly (but it does not resist a few minutes searching the web).

Apart for that, I had no real issue in updating: everything went smooth, and plugins I use work well under helios.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing so major, but some suggestion features are a bit buggy:

- sometimes instead of suggesting to create a method, it suggest a cast, and inserts a cast to `Object`
- when there are interfaces methods with generics, some of them are added as unimplemented even though they exist in the parent class.

These are two things I encountered for the past week.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, Helios does appears to have a pretty critical conflict with the latest oracle JDK patch (JDK 1.6 update 21):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319514

Any version before that is ok.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with [Helios and Oracle JVM 1.6.0 update 21](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319514). Eclipse launcher sets permgen size using Sun-jvm-specific command line option, but Oracle changed vendor string from "Sun Microsystems" to "Oracle", and Eclipse now fails to detect Sun-JVM, so it is not setting right permgen size. Quick solution is to set permgen by yourself in eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting incredibly slow autocomplete. The bug , with a workaround, is here  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317979

Answer (score 1):

We switch to 64bits Helios under Windows 7 recently. We saw a major improvement in memory management no more Out Of Memory errors inside Eclipse. Much better performances as well. But we have a big issue with SVN and SVN Kit plugins they are constantly displaying Malformed Network data errors or Handshake fail errors when synchronising with our repository under svn+ssh. Was perfectly running under 32 bits Indigo or Galileo.

Comment: Comment on my own post : confused by the Eclipse names. We switch to Indigo 64 bits while we were Helios 32 bits. Then came our problem with SVN Kit in svn+ssh protocol constantly showing Handshake failed or Malformed Network data errors.. Sorry for confustion